# nidaqmx: Access an existing task

Tags: python, labview, nidaqmx

I am using the `nidaqmx-python` library for acquiring data. Is it possible to access an existing task, which is already defined in the NI MAX?

Comment: Is `tasks` near the bottom of [this page](https://nidaqmx-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/system.html), or the contents of [this page](https://nidaqmx-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/persisted_task_collection.html), any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution, thanks to the tip from @nekomatic, is:

```
import nidaqmx

system = nidaqmx.system.System.local()  # load local system

task_names = system.tasks.task_names  # returns a list of task names

task = system.tasks[0]  # selected the first task
loaded_task = task.load()  # load the task

sent_samples = []  # list for saving acquired data

with loaded_task:
    loaded_task.timing.cfg_samp_clk_timing(
        rate=2560, 
        sample_mode=nidaqmx.constants.AcquisitionType.CONTINUOUS, 
        samps_per_chan=1000)

    def callback(task_handle, every_n_samples_event_type,
                 number_of_samples, callback_data):
        """
        Callback function/
        """
        print('Every N Samples callback invoked.')

        samples = loaded_task.read(number_of_samples_per_channel=2560)
        sent_samples.extend(samples)

        return 0

    loaded_task.register_every_n_samples_acquired_into_buffer_event(
        200, callback)

    loaded_task.start()

    input('Running task. Press Enter to stop.\n')
```